How to cover 2" gap between drywall and floor
I'm renovating a bathroom in an old house. The drywall is new but the drywallers left a gap of 2 inches between the drywall and floor. I'd appreciate help on the best way to fill this gap
What height of drywall to use for this? I've read that there should always be about a 1/2" expansion gap between drywall and floor. So should the cut piece I use be 1.5" height? or should I leave an additional expansion gap between the existing drywall and cut piece I will be using? if so how much?
Possibly relevant detail:

I will be raising the floor height by adding 1/2" plywood underlayment for tiling. After tiling, I estimate the height will increase by about 1-1.5".
I will be waterproofing the floor wall joint with kerdi membrane to a height of about 4".



If you intend to use a baseboard, ( skirting board in the UK.) you need to do nothing.
The raising of the flooring with subfloor will take up some of the gap.
Then the Kerdi is applied with thinset which can fill in more space.
Once the thinset and tile is down you will have very minimal space that is behind the Kerdi and can be covered with baseboard.
Unless you have kids that play soccer in there or you tapdance with steel toed shoes, you will be fine.

Expansion gaps in drywall are nonsense unless you're in a huge warehouse with continuous walls. There's really nothing in your house more dimensionally stable than pressed gypsum. Ignore that advice. I've installed sheets snug to floors a zillion times and never has anything buckled or cracked as a result.
Also, consider not using drywall. Scrap plywood or OSB would be better, even if you intend to tape to it.
Which gets me to my real concern: The (presumably) unsupported bottom edge of the drywall above. the installers would've been wise to put that 2" filler strip in the middle of the wall and lock it in with a dual tape joint, or to shorten the sheet to allow a wider filler. As it is now, it's at risk of impact damage, floating in the air as it does. I'd see about adding something to support it before you button up the wall.
All that said, if you only have a half inch of gap after flooring, forget about filling it. That's rather pointless unless your choice of baseboard trim needs it for support. Just address the support issue.

Mainly the purpose is not for expansion, but to prevent minor spills from ruining the drywall.
